# Isolating arbitrary bits from a Byte array

Tags: java, android

In my android app I receive from a sensor data with the size of 8 Byte 
via Bluetooth Smart using Android BluetoothGatt. The data contains values for temperature, pressure and humidity. The values are splitted up in the following way.

PRESSURE: 
Byte 1 + Byte 2 + first 4 Bits of Byte 3, other 4 bits are 0

TEMPERATURE:
Byte 4 + Byte 5 + first 4 bits of Byte 6, other 4 bits are 0

HUMIDITY:
Byte 7 + Byte 8

Now at the moment I have a Byte Array that contains the 8 Byte.

My Problem is that I don't know how to extract or isolate the bits for temperature, pressure and humidity as described above.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: Is this byte stream big endian or little endian?

Comment: Is it a byte[] or something else?

Comment: It is big endian and yes it is a byte[].

Comment: Then see Tim B's answer. His answer assumes that the last 4 bits of byte 2 are really 0 and not just unused. Otherwise the maks for byte 2 would be 0x0f. The same for temperatur and quite similar for humidity (the right two parts of Tim's formula only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use bit manipulation operations to extract the values.

For example

```
int pressure = (byte[0]&0xff)<<16+(byte[1]&0xff)<<8+(byte[2]&0xff)
```

(the 16s and 8s may need to be 12 and 4 or 0 4 and 12 depending on exactly what it means).

The operations you need are **<<** which shifts the bits inside the byte around and the **&0xff** which changes the signed byte into a signed integer before you shift it. Otherwise the sign bit will mess things up.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What do you mean with "the 16s and 8s may need to be 12 and 4 or 0 4 and 12 depending on exactly what it means"?

Comment: @ThoKun No need for thanks, although if it helped you feel free to upvote and/or accept the answer using the arrows and tick.